# Upgrading to the last version of Git from the source repository or PPA

Tags: upgrade, git

I want to upgrade git using the [source repository](https://github.com/git/git) within Ubuntu. As you note, the last stable version is 2.0.2, but I have 1.9.4.

I cloned the git repository, but I'm not sure how to continue.

I want to do that in some way I can understand how to interact with the branches and tags of the repository, so I am not searching solutions of [this type](http://lifeonubuntu.com/upgrading-ubuntu-to-use-the-latest-git-version/).

Comment: The next step is to [compile git](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Getting-Started-Installing-Git) - try following the git online documentation, which is generally rather good. If you have difficulties try to seek help at [StackOverflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com), this is not really an Ubuntu related issue.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Install **Git** via [package-management](/questions/tagged/package-management) once and you will be **always have last updates**.

Just run this commands to **install/upgrade** current version:

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git
```

After that you should have this result:

```
$ git --version 
git version 2.0.4
```

Comment: that worked. thanks. The official page http://git-scm.com/download/linux does not have this information. It just says to run the install command. If i do that on my 64bit 14.04 Ubuntu , it just says "git is already the newest version.", which is not true.

Comment: Helped my with windows-linux-subsystem too. since otherwise it only installs git 1.9 with `apt-get install git`